# How to get interested in from facebook via graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to grab facebook user's interested in . I was testing with my own account, I tried many perms, but I get nothing, and in fact, I set my interested in as `women`, and `public`.

does anyone know how to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you grant **user_relationship_details** permission：

[image]

You can always play around with debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/456672354407764/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dinterested_in to find out the approriate permission scope.